# Php: submit form and synchronously call external page GET

Tags: php, forms, get, php-mongodb

I've a form in my web application (php) that insert data on database (mongoDB).

I have to create a script associated with the confirmation button. This script has to call the page mypage.apsx with GET method.

how can I do?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ajax-contacts" action="" method="POST">
  something
</form>
```

Comment: Do you expect a return response from mypage.apsx?

Comment: Make the form action 'mypage.aspx' and do not specify a method (GET is default). Then look at `Request.QueryString()` to find your form values. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Comment: no, I have to do the submitting (POST) to the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents from php.

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com/mypage.aspx?param1=value1&param2=value2");
?>
```